# What to do if wget's progress:mega doen't cut it anymore?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, log-files, wget

I have script for downloading large files in a queue. Now I would really appreciate it, if I had a decent log. Specifying the `-o` or `-a` option is apparently specially made for that, however as of the time I am writing this "very large files", as the manpage states, are no longer 50m of size but rather gigabytes. `--progress=dot:mega` produces 1000 lines of output (plainly it will be 3000*80 dots ('.')) just for a 3GB file. So I am wondering: is there any way to customize the progress style settings, so that i can actually make use of the log feature?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I went down a big long path of playing with modifying the wget output on the fly because I couldn't figure this out either.  Then I found [this debian bugreport](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-closed@lists.debian.org/msg177724.html) which led me to the `-e dotbytes=X` option in wget.  I tested this and it works with my wget-1.12:

```
wget blah --progress=dot -e dotbytes=10M
```

prints a dot for every 10M of output.  You can use 1000M or whatever you like.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit out of date, but just for completeness there is also a `dot:giga` style with wget-1.12

`wget blah --progress=dot:giga`

From the man page:

`If "mega" is not enough then you can use the "giga" style---each dot represents 1M retrieved, there are eight dots in a cluster, and 32 dots on each line (so each line contains 32M).`

This is not as flexible as the `-e, --execute` option, but it is a pre-packaged alternative